# 'Not setting the "method" attribute' deprecations

Tags: api-platform.com

How do I get rid of messages like this?

[2019-10-28 18:18:55] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Not setting the "method" attribute is deprecated and will not be supported anymore in API Platform 3.0, set it for the item operation "api_admin_azvr_users_get_item" of the class "App\API\DTO\AdminAzvrUser". {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Not setting the \"method\" attribute is deprecated and will not be supported anymore in API Platform 3.0, set it for the item operation \"api_admin_azvr_users_get_item\" of the class \"App\API\DTO\AdminAzvrUser\". at /home/avrsites/websites/mydomain.com/symfony/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/ApiLoader.php:206)"} []

Here are the annotations of the referenced DTO class:

```
* @ApiResource(
*      itemOperations={
*          "get"={
*              "path"="/admin_azvr_user/{id}",
*          },
*          "api_admin_azvr_users_get_item"={
*              "swagger_context"={
*                  "operationId"="getAdminAzvrUserItem",
*                  "summary"="Retrieves details on a user (msg_azvr_user table)",
*                  "parameters"= {
*                      {
*                          "name"="id",
*                          "description"="Inquiry ID",
*                          "default"="520",
*                          "in"="path",
*                          "required"=true,
*                          "type"="string"
*                      }
*                  },
*                  "responses"={
*                      "200"={
*                          "description"="Results retrieved"
*                      },
*                      "400"={
*                          "description"="Invalid input"
*                      },
*                      "404"={
*                          "description"="User not found"
*                      }
*                  }
*              }
*          }
*      },
*      collectionOperations={}
* )
```

Where am I supposed to set the "method" attribute?  I tried setting `"method"="GET"` inside the `api_admin_azvr_users_get_item` section, but it did not fix the problem.

My log is full of these messages and I can't find any relevant documentation on how to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be placed on the mentioned item operation, in this case: `api_admin_azvr_users_get_item` which results in:

```
* @ApiResource(
*      itemOperations={
*          "api_admin_azvr_users_get_item"={
*              "method"="GET",
*              "path"="/admin_azvr_user/{id}",
*              "swagger_context"={
*                  "operationId"="getAdminAzvrUserItem",
*                  "summary"="Retrieves details on a user (msg_azvr_user table)",
*                  "parameters"= {
*                      {
*                          "name"="id",
*                          "description"="Inquiry ID",
*                          "default"="520",
*                          "in"="path",
*                          "required"=true,
*                          "type"="string"
*                      }
*                  },
*                  "responses"={
*                      "200"={
*                          "description"="Results retrieved"
*                      },
*                      "400"={
*                          "description"="Invalid input"
*                      },
*                      "404"={
*                          "description"="User not found"
*                      }
*                  }
*              }
*          }
*      },
*      collectionOperations={}
* )
```

If the deprecation note remains try clearing the cache `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: That got rid of the deprecation messages, but caused another problem.

Now all the API methods on the main page are duplicated (with a slight difference in the message).  For example, this is what I see:  

    GET /admin_azvr_user/{id}  Retrieves a AdminAzvrUser resource  
    GET /admin_azvr_user/{id}  Retreives details on a user (msg_azvr_user table)  

The latest API Platform updates have been breaking everything.  Many deprecation messages display in `prod` mode, but are never seen in `dev` mode because exceptions are triggered before the notice can be displayed.

Comment: Well you have got 2 `GET` methods defined on the resource: `get` and `api_admin_azvr_users_get_item `. Do you want different behaviour for both or do you just need 1 `GET` method?

Comment: Where is the documentation on how to define things for the latest version of the API?  It took a lot of trial and error to get my current stuff to work, so my annotations may not be optimal.

Most of examples I've been able to find seem to assume you're using ORM (which I'm not) and are usually more confusing than helpful.

What would be useful are complete annotation examples of working code for custom DTOs, not just fragments of stuff scattered in various locations.  So far, I have not been able to find much like that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to translate my old annotations to the new way.

Comment: I agree with you that documentation can be improved, however that is out of scope of this question. I have edited my answer to match witch what I believe you expect to happen.